# How to add javascript library to Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there some way to add javascript libraries to project for autocmplete?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Package Manager](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) and then install snippets for javascript library(if there is any) although snippets for HTML, CSS and even Bootstrap. I hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

there is a package called SublimeCodeIntel
i've got it working for python, but am strugling myself for javascript support.
it is in there, i've seen it at work, but I am missing some settings myself I think.

in any case, here is the link, check it out:
https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel